# Passing URL Parameters into an iFrame Source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I am setting up a real estate website that will give people the option to search homes and narrow down the search using different options, such as price, location, number or rooms, etc.

Currently, I have created a form that outputs to a URL similar to this:

```
www.websitename.com/search/url=www.sitetwo.com?param=1%param=2%param=3
```

That particular page (www.websitename.com/search) loads an iframe. I need the iFrame source to pull from the second part of the URL created by the search form (www.sitetwo.com?param=1%param=2%param=3).

How would I go about doing this? I assuming its a piece of javascript, but my JS is limited. So getting going in the right direction has been tricky.

**EDIT - Added for Clarification**
The sitetwo.com URL is a URL I have to use as it is part of the real estate listings solution (basically, it allows to display listings from a third party provider on our website). It is how they recommend integrating with their system.

Here is a site doing something similar to what I am trying to achieve:
http://tierraantigua.com

Comment: If the source of the second page is in PHP, why don't you simply use the `$_GET` data and have the PHP do all the work>

Comment: @Fluffeh You mean the $_GET global variable, or safe to say _GET method. ;)

Comment: After looking into this, it seems like a logical solution but my concern would be if a field was left blank - would that cause an issue with the PHP if it was expecting a value and did not receive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't allow arbitrary URIs in your iframes.

First, put the whole URI into one field of the originating form. This will make sure the URL will be encoded and doesn't interfere with other GET parameters. On the destination page [get the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values) and then use [decodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp).

Comment: +1 for the URL encoding idea. But instead of doing the `decodeURIComponent` in the second (destination page) (how would you do that in JS? It will be processed on the server) it is possibly easier to  do the `decodeURIComponent` in the parent before constructing the target iframe src URL, right?